How can I write an Excel file in NodeJS and download it?
I want to retrieve data from the database and and write it on an Excel file. I use xlsx lib but there is a problem that shows to me when I open the file:

Excel cannot open the file ****.xlsx because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Backend:
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import db from './db/connect.js'; 
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';   
import { body, validationResult } from 'express-validator';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import multer from 'multer';
import * as xlsx from 'xlsx/xlsx.mjs';
import fs from 'fs'

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();


app.get('/export', async (req, res) => {
  const query = 'SELECT card_title, code, description_x, description_y FROM cards';

  db.query(query, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error fetching cards:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Database error' });
    }

    try {
      const workbook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
      const worksheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(result);
      xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Cards');
      const excelFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'cards.xlsx');
      xlsx.writeFile(workbook, excelFilePath);

      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
      res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=cards.xlsx');

      res.sendFile(excelFilePath, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error sending Excel file:', err);
          return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error exporting data' });
        }

        setTimeout(() => {
          fs.unlink(excelFilePath, (unlinkErr) => {
            if (unlinkErr) {
              console.error('Error deleting temporary file:', unlinkErr);
            }
          });
        }, 5000);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating Excel file:', error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error generating Excel file' });
    }
  });
});

Frontend:

    const handleExport = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/export');
        const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = url;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'cards.xlsx');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('Error exporting data');
      }
    };

.....

<Dialog>
        <DialogTrigger><Button>Export</Button></DialogTrigger>
        <DialogContent>
            <DialogHeader>
            <DialogTitle>Export Cards in Excel Format</DialogTitle>
            <div className='flex justify-center items-center gap-2 '>
             <Button onClick={handleExport} className='my-9 p-5 '><RxDownload className='p-1 w-9 h-9' /></Button>               
            </div>
            </DialogHeader>
        </DialogContent>
</Dialog>


Have you checked that response.data contains the expected XML data and not the JSON error message or something else? Have you tried to open the generated file directly on the server? First, I would try to find out if it's a backend or frontend problem and remove the other side from the equation.

@jabaa it shows me this error when i request it:
{
"message": "Error generating Excel file",
"error": "cannot save file D:\MyProjects\CardSystem\Backend\cards.xlsx"
}

That's the content of the file? Now, it should be pretty clear that the problem is caused by the backend code and unrelated to the frontend. Can you create and provide a [mcve] without the server? I guess, the error comes from xlsx.writeFile(workbook, excelFilePath);.

I've removed the MERN tag, because the problem is unrelated to Mongo, Express and React.

I've used xlsx in my app node.js app recently - your backend code looks fine.
I've, however, handled my download on the backend so i can't comment on the front-end.
This is how I handled my download:
try {
    const workbook = xlsx.utils.book_new();
    const worksheet = xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(result);
    xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, "Cards");
    const excelFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "cards.xlsx");
    xlsx.writeFile(workbook, excelFilePath);

    res.download(excelFilePath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }
      fs.unlink(excelFilePath, (unlinkErr) => {
        if (unlinkErr) {
          console.error("Error deleting temporary file:", unlinkErr);
        }
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error creating Excel file:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Error generating Excel file" });
}

Up until sending your file to the front-end your code looks very similar to mine, so maybe try searching for a bug where you're fetching the data on the front-end(?)
Hope this helps you at least a bit.
